# Importing a module with classes that uses standard library causes redefinition errors

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I am having this problem in a very big project so I isolated the error as much as it can be isolated.

Lets say I have a very simple module named `TestModule` that only exports `TestStruct` that has only a std::string member in it.

```
// TestModule.ixx
module;
#include <string>

export module TestModule;

export struct TestStruct {
    std::string str;
};
```

And I have a header file of a struct `TestUser` that uses this `TestStruct`

```
// TestUser.h

import TestModule;

struct TestUser {
    void TestFunc(TestStruct ts);
};
```

Lastly I have some other header file that includes `TestUser.h` along with some other headers that includes some other headers that also includes some other headers and so on.. For the sake of the question, I distilled unrelated includes from the include tree and only wrote the related header(s) here that is able to make the problem reproducible.

Instead of <string> you can write every other std headers like vector, iostream, complex, variant. Whatever std header I tried, it reproduced the error with a different error message but the main idea of all the erros are redefinition of something.

```
// OtherUser.h

#include "test.h"
#include <string>
```

To keep it simple, lets say I have a main.cpp like this:

```
// main.cpp
#include "OtherUser.h"

int main()
{

}
```

Trying to compile main.cpp in this setting, it starts the output with:

```
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include\xtr1common(34,2): 
error C2953: 'std::integral_constant': class template has already been defined
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include\xtr1common(21,8): 
message : see declaration of 'std::integral_constant'
```

and continues the output with logs very similar to this then ends with:

```
fatal  error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
```

**If you add `#include <string>` to the start of TestUser.h it fixes the problem.**

OR

**If you remove the `#include <string>` from OtherUser.h it fixes the problem.**

Why do you think this happens? What can I do in the module to prevent this. I am trying to convert to modules in a big project but this problem is making it impossible. Even tho I include std headers in the module, should I also include them wherever I use that module even tho I won't use those std headers in the module user file itself.

Comment: Seems like mixing `import` and `#include` of standard headers just doesn't work yet. [A known compiler limitation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dk_C_E8AtRs&t=1990s) accoring to mr STL.